# Dropping MySQL Archive Databases

Tags: mysql, database, windows, archive

I have MySQL 5.0 running on a Windows 2003 server.  I was trying to drop an archive database when I received this error:

Error dropping database (can't rmdir './database_name/', errno: 17)

There are ARM and ARN files in every directory for every archive database on the server.  From what I can tell, these are generated during an optimize.

Is it safe to remove these files manually so that a drop command in mysql will go through normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could mean for example - database directory contains some files that is not belongs to mysql database. For instance .empty file.

Comment: I looked for other files, and there isn't anything in there except for ARM files.  I think an optimize I did tried to optimize the archive databases, and this left ARM files around.  I'm just not sure if they are safe to delete.

Comment: .arm is metadata for archive files (in version 5.0. It's deprecated since 5.1). I believe if you are going to drop the whole database - it is safe to delete its database directory (/database_name/ as you wrote) just using OS tools. You can copy these files into some backup place if you are unsure, .arm file (as metadata) should not be changed frequently, you will be able to restore them from backup without problem.